# R First Row By Group When Condition Is Met

Tags: r, data.table

```
dataHAVE=data.frame(STUDENT=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
SCORE=c(0,1,1,5,1,2,1,1,1),
CAT=c(3,10,7,4,5,0,4,5,1),
FOX=c(5,0,10,8,9,1,8,9,0))

dataWANT=data.frame(STUDENT=c(1,2,3),
SCORE=c(1,1,1),
CAT=c(10,5,4),
FOX=c(0,9,8))
```

I have 'dataHAVE' and want 'dataWANT' which takes the first row for every 'STUDENT' when 'SCORE' equals to 1. I am seeking a data.table solution because of it being a large data. I try this but do not know how to set the criteria for 'SCORE'

```
dataWANT[,.SD[1],by = key(STUDENT)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), grouped by 'STUDENT', specify the logical condition in `i`, get the index of the first row (`.I[1]`), extract that column (`$V1`) and subset the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataHAVE)[dataHAVE[SCORE == 1, .I[1], STUDENT]$V1]
```

---

`.I` returns row index.  If we don't have a grouping column, it would return a `vector` i.e.

```
setDT(dataHAVE)[SCORE == 1, .I]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

when we provide the grouping column, by default, the `.I` returns with a named column `V1` (we could override it by changing the name)

```
setDT(dataHAVE)[SCORE == 1, .(colindex = .I[1]), STUDENT]
#    STUDENT colindex
#1:       1        2
#2:       2        5
#3:       3        7
```

Nowe, we have two columns, 'STUDENT', 'colindex'.  We are specifically interested in the 'colindex', so extract with standard procedures (`$` or `[[`) and then use that as row index in `i`

```
i1 <- setDT(dataHAVE)[SCORE == 1, .(colindex = .I[1]), STUDENT]$colindex
i1
#[1] 2 5 7
```

This we use for subsetting

```
dataHAVE[i1]
```

Comment: thank you so much could you just help me to understand the meaning of '.I' and $V1

Comment: this is so amazing thanks so much! my final question is, if i do not want to output but save it instead what do I modify? I tried to get rid of '.' in '.I' but am wondering what do i exclude so to not print it but just modify it?

Comment: @bvowe You can assign it to new object `out <- setDT(dataHAVE)[dataHAVE[SCORE == 1, .I[1], STUDENT]$V1]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  dataHAVE,
  ave(SCORE==1, STUDENT, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) == min(which(x)))
)
```

which gives

```
  STUDENT SCORE CAT FOX
2       1     1  10   0
5       2     1   5   9
7       3     1   4   8
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1.** There is a straightforward and comprehensive solution in two lines:

```
dataWANT <- dataHAVE[dataHAVE$SCORE == 1,]            #Filter score equals to 1
dataWANT <- dataWANT[!duplicated(dataWANT$STUDENT), ] #Remove duplicated students
```

**Solution 2.** However, if you prefer to solve in one line:

```
dataWANT <- dataHAVE[!duplicated(paste0(dataHAVE$STUDENT, dataHAVE$SCORE)) & dataHAVE$SCORE ==1, ]
```

That creates a logical vector showing which of the combinations that are not duplicated of preceding elements, and combine it with a test if 'SCORE' is 1.

Comment: The solution 1 here is simple and easy to understand. I don't known why people prefer complicated and less readable solutions that are not necessarily more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match`  to get 1st row where `SCORE = 1` for each `STUDENT`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dataHAVE)
dataHAVE[, .SD[match(1, SCORE)], STUDENT]

#   STUDENT SCORE CAT FOX
#1:       1     1  10   0
#2:       2     1   5   9
#3:       3     1   4   8
```